# CSV to GeoJSON conversion

Tags: java, mongodb, geojson, mongodb-java

I want to convert a CSV line into a GeoJSON object. I am using CSVReader. Hence, nextLine[] has all the separated tokens.
I want to create BasicDBObject which has various attributes stored. I am doing it following way.

```
new BasicDBObject("attribute1",nextLine[0]).append("attribute2",nextLine[1])
```

What I want to achieve is having a document like this in MongoDB
    {
     attribute1: name
     attribute2: address
     location:{  type : "Point" ,
                 coordinates : [lat, long]
              }
     attrribute3: phonenumber
     }
How do I do this using BasicDBObject?`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is using the BasicDBObjectBuilder, an utility class to build DBObjects. You can do something like that:

```
BasicDBObject toInsert = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
    .add("attribute1",nextLine[0])
    .add("attribute2",nextLine[1])
    .add(" attrribute3",nextLine[2])
    .push("location")
        .add("type", "Point")
        .add("coordinates", new double[] { nextLine[3], nextLine[4] })
    .pop()
    .get()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it the other way

```
double latLong[] = new double[]{10.0, 30.0};
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("attr1",nextLine[0])
         .append("attr2", nextLine[1]
    .append("location",new BasicDBObject("type","Point")
.append("coordinates",latLong)) 
    .append("attr3", nextLine[3])
```

This also works as desired

Comment: It works perfectly too. I tend to use BasicDBObjectBuilder for complex DBObject. It's reasonable DSL for building DBObjects.